# Updating a large table from another takes a long time (more than 6 hours) in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-update

I want to "update" **31 columns** of *table A* (**~ 22 million rows**) from *table B* (**~ 31 million rows**).
I created a temporary table with only the columns I was interested in (i.e. 31) and also in order to eliminate a second condition (number of rows is also reduced to **~ 22 million**). Next, I created an index for two columns : "column1" of the temporary table and table A (used for join). Then I created a "multicolumn indexes" on all the columns of the temporary table except for the column "column1". Unfortunately, the update is still very long (I stopped the request after 6 hours of loading)
I don't know much about the indexes. Is there any bad practice in what I have done? Are there solutions to considerably reduce the duration of the update? 
Thanks in advance.
Part of the sql script and an explain plan of the update are below :

```
Create temp table if not exists table_TMP as (
        select
        "column1",
        "column2",
        "column3",
        all other columns...
        from table_B
        where one_column_of_table_B=TRUE
);
CREATE INDEX if not exists idx_table_TMP
    ON table_TMP USING btree
    ("column1")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

//multiindex on 31 columns
CREATE INDEX if not exists idx2_table_TMP ON table_TMP (
    "column2",
    "column3",
    all other columns...);

update table_A set
    "table_A_column2"=tmp."column2",
    "table_A_column3"=tmp."column3",
    all other columns...
    FROM table_TMP tmp
    Where  table_A.column1 = tmp.column1;

//explain of the update :
"Update on table_A  (cost=5798151.63..24891890.93 rows=21716146 width=4104)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=5798151.63..24891890.93 rows=21716146 width=4104)"
"        Hash Cond: ((tmp.column1)::text = (table_A.column1)::text)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on table_TMP tmp  (cost=0.00..770061.46 rows=21716146 width=2342)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=622658.39..622658.39 rows=22008739 width=1798)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on table_A  (cost=0.00..622658.39 rows=22008739 width=1798)"
```

Comment: `Where  table_A.column1 = tmp.column1;` Is tmp.column1 guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Creating new table could be more efficient...

Comment: If you turn your update into a select on both tables, how long does that take?  Please post an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
@wildplasser yes it is.

Comment: @Abelisto ok but how ? the select takes a long time too

Comment: @jjanes the "select" has been running all day. I decided to stop the request so not possible to have the result of the option ANALYZE.
select explain without options : 
"Hash Join  (cost=2007176.08..17203453.39 rows=21716146 width=2674)"
"  Hash Cond: ((tmp.column1)::text = (tableA.column1)::text)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on tmp(cost=0.00..721811.46 rows=21716146 width=2336)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=633632.26..633632.26 rows=22396626 width=374)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on tableA(cost=0.00..633632.26 rows=22396626 width=374)"

Comment: In that case: why don't you create a UNIQUE index? Also: `width=4104` Your table_A is rather wide. Is your data model normalised? Is there an index on column1?

Comment: Is the SELECT can't run then the UPDATE is certainly doomed.  Can you see what it is is doing?  (taking all the CPU, grinding the hard drive, blocked on a lock, etc?  What if you set `enable_hashjoin=off`?

Comment: @wildpasser you are right, I left the columns to update but for the select it is not necessary. The model is currently normalized but follows a "BI" logic. Yes there is an index. By deleting the 31 columns of my table A,  I was able to finish "create as select" in 3 hours. Here is the explain analyze.
In your opinion, can we further reduce the execution time?

Comment: `"Hash Join  (cost=1959156.81..16310921.17 rows=21716146 width=2674) (actual time=1406705.487..10774283.484 rows=21716146 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((tmp.column1)::text = (tableA.column1)::text)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=777 read=408889, local read=504650, temp read=808109 written=808109"
"  ->  Seq Scan on tmp_etab  (cost=0.00..721811.46 rows=21716146 width=2336) (actual time=16.284..2724765.371 rows=21716146 loops=1)"
`

Comment: `"        Buffers: local read=504650"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=626900.14..626900.14 rows=21723414 width=374) (actual time=1390443.257..1390443.257 rows=21723414 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 16384  Batches: 4096  Memory Usage: 842kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=777 read=408889, temp written=330619"
"        ->  Seq Scan on TableA  (cost=0.00..626900.14 rows=21723414 width=374) (actual time=0.049..838654.806 rows=21723414 loops=1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=777 read=408889"
"Planning Time: 42.458 ms"
"Execution Time: 10866675.755 ms"`

Comment: @jjanes does that answer the first part of the question? what does `enable_hashjoin=off` mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should post new plans by editing your question rather than in the comments, that way they could be formatted correctly.

> ```
> Buckets: 16384  Batches: 4096  Memory Usage: 842kB
> ```

Your work_mem seems to be 1MB.  That is low on any modern system, and especially for this type of query.  As a result of the low memory, each table is divided into 4096 batches and processed one batch at a time.  In read-only statement, that should not be too bad because all the IO is done sequentially (I have no idea why it took 3 hours though, that does seem pretty long and I can only guess that your hardware is really quite horrible).  But for an UPDATE, this is completely devastating as it can't update the batched table files, it has to update the original table.  It is essentially making 4096 passes over the table to be updated.

Increasing work_mem should make both the select and the update faster, but the update may still be unusably slow.  Making a new table from the select and then replacing the old table with the new one maybe be the best option.

If you do `set enable_hashjoin=off;` in your current session, it will force the planner to use some other join method, and it might be interesting to see what that is but there is not much reason to think it would be hugely faster.